# Content Provider and Image storage

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I want to share some image Icons between two applications. I stored the icons in a folder from Application 1 and tried use the folder from application 2. That time i got some permission issue. I was not able add the permission also because it is not a rooted device.

So i am now trying to store the icons in a content provider. Is it possible to store the images in a Content provider ? Is there any other good method to implement this ? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ContentProviders are not used for storage.  They are used to a public interface to database access either from different application components, different applications or both based on permissions.

What you can do though is store the images as a binary data set (BLOB) in a database.  Then use a content provider with public permissions to query for the image and add new images to the database.  However if you are just trying to store your application icons, you should just have these in each project using the res folder.  Don't fight the SDK if you don't need to.

Hope this will point you in the right direction.  Look through Android's ContentResolver and ContentProvider API for more information.

Comment: private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
          "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + 
          " (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
          + "icons blob not null, name text not null);"; this is the create query i am using. IS this correct

Comment: @Paru this looks correct, although you dont' need the + in between autoincrement.  Also I would use caps for the SQL keywords as this is what most people do.  You also want to create your database in an SQLiteOpenHelper that will be used in your ContentProvider

Answer (score 0):

If you stored the icons on App1 as resources (drawables) you can simply access them by using the package name and knowing the resources ID or name (since it's your own app I assume you know these ;-))

Take a look at [PackageManager.getResourcesForApplication](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getResourcesForApplication%28java.lang.String%29).
To access resources by name you can use [Resources.getIdentifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: I am not storing the icons in the drawable. I creating a new folder with the required icons